# Bmi calculator kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm in the process of learning android studio and kotlin. I have no experience with java so while learning kotlin I'm only drawing on experience I have from C# programming. I am trying to make a simple script which takes the input from the text field of height and weight take them and put them into a formula that gives the BMI score which is then printed everything works when I tested the script by simply multiply or adding height and weight together to test so I know the general code works. How can I fix my problem atm the output Is always 0 I've messed around using values much larger and it appears to not be multiplying by 10,000 at the end any fixes guys? thanks.

```
    package com.example.test

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.TextView

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val btnChangeText = findViewById(R.id.btn_change_text) as Button
            val tvBMI = findViewById(R.id.output_BMI) as TextView
            val weight = findViewById(R.id.input_weight) as EditText
            val height = findViewById(R.id.input_height) as EditText

            btnChangeText.setOnClickListener {
               val bmiWeight = weight.text.toString().toInt()
               val bmiHeight = height.text.toString().toInt()
               val bmiCalc =  bmiWeight /  bmiHeight /  bmiHeight * 10000
                tvBMI.text = bmiCalc.toString()
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like bmiWeight and bmiHeight are integers. Integer division results in a chopping off of the remainder or simply 0 if the denominator is larger.

Try:

```
bmiWeight.toDouble() / bmiHeight / bmiHeight * 10000
```

or get bmiHeight and bmiWeight as a double to begin with

```
val bmiWeight = weight.text.toString().toDouble()
```

Comment: brilliant worked a treat. so I don't end up a whole number at the end I changed the output text back to an integer at the end thank you.                                                                          
            tvBMI.text = bmiCalc.toInt().toString()